# Mirroring PC screen to android via USB

Tags: usb, usb-connection-mode, remote-control

There seems to be slight variations of this question that have been asked to no avail, but is there a way to mirror my pc desktop to my android device STRICTLY using a USB cable?
I've seen may solutions for this using wifi such as splashtop and windows remote desktop, but my I don't have access to wifi or mobile data on my android device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Both ends lack functionality for this. USB isn't designed to output in this way without pricey adapters that act as port replicators, forcing your CPU to act as a virtual video card, then outputting through a video port on the replicator, and adding USB, Ethernet, etc. But then you'd need to go from that adapter to your phone, and your phone has no inputs for this type of communication, or software functionality to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can using "Mobile Pc Monitor" you can do just that. there is also Twomon USB but that cost $9.
Download the free "Mobile Pc Monitor" app from google play and the server from http://www.usbmobilemonitor.com
after installation go to display properties on you pc and click detect. change the mode to mobile pc monitor display and it should work depending on your phone.  (and no pc reboot)

"TurboFool" apparently doesn't know much about data cables or software... 
in the end its all 1s and 0s and usb data cables and computers love those things. 
DVI, and HDMI cables are designed FOR monitors to connect directly to the displays control board.
that gives the best refresh rates, and quality. Some phones even have Mini HDMI ports to steam video. 
I been doing the same thing with my psp via data cable and pspDisplay so it was a matter of time to find a program that does the same for my android phone.

You can stream video over usb via software and thats exactly what the app I mentioned does.
The server program running on your PC captures the video thats sent to the monitor changes it to a usable format and sends that to the phone via data cable. The app then interprets those signals and displays the image. 
I been looking for the same solution for days and just found it. It works on my Galaxy S4 np.
you can definitely send those 1s and 0s though the usb cable but at some loss of quality.

Both those programs give you the ability to extend your display to the phone as if it were another monitor. Thats something "PspDisplay" didn't do. 
you can also just duplicate one of your monitors to the phone. 
touch screen works as a mouse as well so its not just a monitor its a whole new input device.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing a VNC server on your computer.

With VNC installed, you can use this: https://f-droid.org/en/packages/android.androidVNC/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm a *bit* late to the *party* ;P but it's not all "doom-n-gloom" on this front.

An (apparently) Argentinian software company has published a software which claims to do exactly what you ask here -- the company's name is Shape -- you can read about them here --> http://www.shape.ag/en/company/

The name of their software widget is **iDisplay** but they claim it works with iOS, macOS, Android and Windows. You can read more about it here --> http://www.getidisplay.com/ and even download it -- it's supposed to be free of cost.

DownLoadCrew's review:

> Blockquote

Run out of space on your desktop? There is no need to rush out to the shops to buy a new monitor, particularly if you are one of the millions of people who own an iPhone or iPad, or an Android tablet or mobile. iDisplay is a tool that can be used to transform your mobile device into a second display for your Mac or PC so you can take advantage of a little extra desktop workspace.

The software is made up of two different components – the desktop software which needs to be installed on your PC or Mac, and the mobile app which is available for both iOS and Android – and you have the option of connecting over a USB connection, or wifi. iDisplay can be used in to different mode with the first turning your mobile device into an extension of your desktop, and the second enabling you to mirror what you see on your monitor.

iDisplay can be used in various ways. If you have your computer connected to your TV, you could use your phone to house an onscreen remote so you can control playback from the sofa. When you are working at your desk, you can limit distractions by using your tablet’s screen to display your Twitter feed or Facebook timeline. It can also be used to move control panels out of the way of other program windows.

iDisplay has numerous benefits over a regular monitor, the first of which is portability. While it is possible to change the configuration of a multi-monitor setup, cables and desktop space mean that this is not going to be something you want to do all that often. In the case of iDisplay, all you need to do is re-position your phone or tablet and then use the configuration tool to indicate where it is in relation to your monitor. The wireless aspect means that it is also possible to use the app to keep an eye on your desktop when you step away from your computer, so you need never be out of touch.

Verdict:

A low-cost and incredibly useful way to gain extra work space and a very helpful way of interacting with your computer.

> Blockquote

Disclaimer: 1) I have **not** downloaded, installed or tried out this software.

2) I **do NOT** work for the publishers of this software or represent them commercially or in any other capacity. I just encountered their software / website during my routine Internet research on Android apps.

But I hope **iDisplay** meets your specific requirement(s) / resolves your issue(s).